# Getting unauthorized response when making DocuSign Admin API call

Tags: node.js, json, jwt, postman, docusignapi

I'm trying to use Docusign's Admin API to create a user in my organization.

Here's what I did:

1. Created a JWT for the application
2. Called Docusign's Admin api (/oauth/token) to create the access token and use it in my API calls

When I call the route `POST https://api-d.docusign.net/management/v2/organizations/{organizationID}/users`

I get a 401 Unauthorized response with no more informations.

Comment: What `scopes` are you using when requesting the JWT token?

Answer (score 0):

The [DocuSign Admin API](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/) requires additional set of scopes when obtaining tokens using JWT:

[image]